# Upgrading web app: .NET 2.0 to .NET 4.0

Tags: asp.net, iis, configuration

I'm in the process of upgrading some older web apps from ASP.NET 2.0/3.5 to 4.0 as time permits. So far I've coordinated with my operations group to roll the changes out at off times, due to the need to recycle IIS after changing the ASP.NET version.

My question is let's say we upgrade the site to ASP.NET 4.0 in IIS, but leave a 2.0/3.5 web.config file in the site. Will the site continue to run with the older settings, or will we get a configuration error when users browse the site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you will have issues using the old web.config file. Please see this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd483478.aspx

Read the "Note" section in particular.